# Why doesn't 'utf8-c8' encoding work when reading filehandles

Tags: raku

I wish to read byte sequences that will not decode as valid UTF-8, specifically byte sequences that correspond to high and low surrogates code points. The result should be a raku string.

I [read](https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode#UTF8-C8) that, in raku, the 'utf8-c8' encoding can be used for this purpose.

Consider code point [U+D83F](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+D83F). It is a high surrogate (reserved for the high half of UTF-16 surrogate pairs).

U+D83F has a byte sequence of 0xED 0xA0 0xBF, if encoded as UTF-8.

### Slurping a file? Works

If I slurp a file containing this byte sequence, using 'utf8-c8' as the encoding, I get the expected result:

```bash
echo -n $'\ud83f' >testfile # Create a test file containing the byte sequence
```

myprog1.raku:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/raku
$*OUT.encoding('utf8-c8');
print slurp('testfile', enc => 'utf8-c8');
```

```
$ ./myprog1.raku | od -An -tx1
 ed a0 bf
```

✔️ expected result

### Slurping a filehandle? Doesn't work

But if I switch from slurping a file path to slurping a filehandle, it doesn't work, even though I set the filehandle's encoding to 'utf8-c8':

myprog2.raku

```
#!/usr/local/bin/raku
$*OUT.encoding('utf8-c8');
my $fh = open "testfile", :r, :enc('utf8-c8');
print slurp($fh, enc => 'utf8-c8');
#print $fh.slurp; # I tried this too: same error
```

```
$ ./myprog2.raku
Error encoding UTF-8 string: could not encode Unicode Surrogate codepoint 55359 (0xD83F)
  in block <unit> at ./myprog2.raku line 4
```

### Environment

*Edit 2022-10-30: I originally used my distro's package (Fedora Linux 36: Rakudo version 2020.07). I just downloaded the latest Rakudo binary release (2022.07-01). Result was the same.*

```
$ /usr/local/bin/raku --version
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.07.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.07.
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux hx90 5.19.16-200.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Oct 16 22:50:04 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 36 (Thirty Six)
Release:        36
Codename:       ThirtySix
```

Comment: Can you let us know what platform? On an older MacOS w/ Rakudo 2022.07 both seem to  work: 
`~$ cat r_meade_testfile.txt | raku r_meade_slurp.p6
    \ud83f`
 and 
 `~$ cat r_meade_testfile.txt | raku r_meade_filehandle.p6
    \ud83f`

Comment: Is that really version 2020.07 you're using?  Not 2022.07? If it *is* 2020.07, then I suggest upgrading first before potentially filing a bug report

Comment: I updated to the latest Rakudo binary release just now. I experienced same result. I added details about my platform to my question.